# PHP not printing lowest mysqli ID number

Tags: php, mysqli

The below code isn't printing out the lowest number in the database table. There is currently 4 entries - only three print out. The lowest ID number, doesn't print.

Code:

```
### Run Query
$query = "SELECT * from `Reminders`";
$run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
### Fetch Data
if($check > 0)
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
  {
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $Text = $row['rText'];
    $Number = $row['rNumber'];
    $Date = $row['rDate'];
    $Time = $row['rTime'];

    echo "'$Text' to '$Number' on $Date at $Time.<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to do two fetched: `mysqli_fetch_array()` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`? The first one probably eats one of your rows.

Comment: You want `$check = mysqli_num_rows($run);`

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$check` part, and that's where the lowest one gone. For counting number of rows returned, use `mysqli_num_rows()` function.

```
### Run Query
$query = "SELECT * from `Reminders`";
$run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
// Change here... :)
$check = mysqli_num_rows($run);
### Fetch Data
if ($check > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $Text = $row['rText'];
    $Number = $row['rNumber'];
    $Date = $row['rDate'];
    $Time = $row['rTime'];
    echo "'$Text' to '$Number' on $Date at $Time.<br/>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From php manual :- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

> `mysqli_num_rows()` function is used for returning the number of rows
>   in the result set.

So, Just Replace this of code,

```
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
```

with this line,

```
$check = mysqli_num_rows($run);
```